# many WHERE, AND OR clause to store datas in db with sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

In my project, I am using the [yeoman express generator](https://github.com/petecoop/generator-express) with ORM [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/).

With the method [`findOrCreate`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findorcreateoptions-promiseinstance-created), I am trying to create many datas to store in Users model/table.

This is my query:

```
db.User.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    username: 'johny',
    description: 'this is johnny',
    email: 'johny[###]example.com'
  },
  and:
  {
      username: 'jenny',
      description: 'this is jenny',
      email: 'jenny[###]example.com'
  },
  or: [
  {
      username: 'nowis',
      description: 'this is N0w1s',
      email: 'nowis[###]example.com'
  },
  {
      username: 'brad',
      description: 'this is brad',
      email: 'brad[###]example.com'
  }
  ],
}).then(function (user) {
  console.log("ok");
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

No error occured, but the problem is that with this query, I store only the datas concerning `johny`, not the others.

Of course, there is no entry in my database concerning users table, except, once I launch grunt, I have now the entry concerning `johny` because the entry was persisted by the query I wrote below.

Where am I wrong in this query ?

Comment: what is the expected behavior?

Comment: @Adam, the expected behavior is to create all data from this query.

Comment: If you'd like to create multiple records, you can use `bulkCreate`. I don't understand why you're using `findOrCreate`.

Comment: @Adam It seems that I missed this function, make an answer in that way I valid your suggestion, thankyou by the way !